# Tensorflow: GradientTape giving gradients with NaN

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I've been trying to train a custom style transfer net with AdaIN. The only problem I'm facing now is the gradients I'm getting are all NaN values, right from the first epoch. Currently using TF 2.6.1.

Here's the custom training loop and loss function:

```py
def _compute_mean_std(self, feats : tf.Tensor, eps=1e-8):
    """
    feats: Features should be in shape N x H x W x C
    """
    mean = tf.math.reduce_mean(feats, axis=[1,2], keepdims=True)
    std = tf.math.reduce_std(feats, axis=[1,2], keepdims=True) + eps
    return mean, std

def criterion(self, stylized_img : tf.Tensor, style_img : tf.Tensor, t : tf.Tensor):
    stylized_content_feats = self.model.encode(stylized_img)
    stylized_feats = self.model.encode(stylized_img, return_all=True)
    style_feats = self.model.encode(style_img, return_all=True)

    content_loss = self.mse_loss(t, stylized_content_feats)

    style_loss = 0
    for f1, f2 in zip(stylized_feats, style_feats):
        m1, s1 = self._compute_mean_std(f1)
        m2, s2 = self._compute_mean_std(f2)
        style_loss += self.mse_loss(m1, m2) + self.mse_loss(s1, s2)

    return content_loss + self.style_weight * style_loss

def train(self):
    step = 0
    while step < self.num_iter:
        content_batch = self.content_iter.get_next()
        if content_batch.shape[0] != self.batch_size:
            content_batch = self.content_iter.get_next()

        style_batch = self.style_iter.get_next()
        if style_batch.shape[0] != self.batch_size:
            style_batch = self.style_iter.get_next()

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            stylized_imgs, t = self.model(dict(content_imgs=content_batch, style_imgs=style_batch, alpha=1.0))
            loss = self.criterion(stylized_imgs, style_batch, t)

        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_weights))

        # log and save every 200 batches
        if step % 200 == 0:
            print(f'Training loss (for one batch) at step {step}: {loss}')
            print(f'Seen so far: {(step+1)*self.batch_size} samples')

            self.model.save_weights(f'./checkpoints/adain_e{step}.ckpt')

        step += 1

    print("Finished training...")
    self.model.save_weights('saved_model/adain_weights.h5')
```

I can't figure out why it's doing that. It doesn't throw an error when `_compute_mean_std` calculates mean/std in the format NxCxHxW though, which is not what I want either. Adding a transpose also causes this when trying to calculate it in the correct shape.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible this way

**[ Sample ]:**

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
num_iter = 1000
train_generator_batch_size = 1
batch_size = 1
WIDTH = 256
HEIGHT = 256
CHANNEL = 3

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Definition / Class
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
def create_image_generator( ):
    variables = pd.read_excel('F:\\temp\\Python\\excel\\Book 7.xlsx', index_col=None, header=[0], dtype=str)
    
    train_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        
        validation_split=0.2,
    
    )

    train_image_ds = train_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe = variables,
        directory=None,
        x_col= 'Image',
        y_col= 'Label',
        weight_col=None,
        target_size=( WIDTH, HEIGHT ),
        color_mode='rgb',
        classes=None,
        class_mode='categorical',           ####
        batch_size=train_generator_batch_size,
        shuffle=True,
        seed=None,
        save_to_dir=None,
        save_prefix='',
        save_format='png',
        subset=None,
        interpolation='nearest',
        validate_filenames=True,
    )

    return train_image_ds

class gradient_tape_optimizer( ):
    def __init__ ( self, model, num_iter, content_iter, batch_size ):
        
        self.num_iter = num_iter
        self.content_iter = content_iter
        self.style_iter = content_iter 
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.model = model
        self.loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy( from_logits=False, 
            reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO, 
            name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy' )
            
        self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam( learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, name='Nadam' )

    def _compute_mean_std( self, feats : tf.Tensor, eps=1e-8 ):
        """
        feats: Features should be in shape N x H x W x C
        """
        mean = tf.math.reduce_mean(feats, axis=[1,2], keepdims=True)
        std = tf.math.reduce_std(feats, axis=[1,2], keepdims=True) + eps
        return mean, std

    def criterion( self, stylized_img : tf.Tensor, style_img : tf.Tensor, t : tf.Tensor ):
        stylized_content_feats = self.model.encode(stylized_img)
        stylized_feats = self.model.encode(stylized_img, return_all=True)
        style_feats = self.model.encode(style_img, return_all=True)

        content_loss = self.mse_loss(t, stylized_content_feats)

        style_loss = 0
        for f1, f2 in zip(stylized_feats, style_feats):
            m1, s1 = self._compute_mean_std(f1)
            m2, s2 = self._compute_mean_std(f2)
            style_loss += self.mse_loss(m1, m2) + self.mse_loss(s1, s2)

        return content_loss + self.style_weight * style_loss

    def train( self ):
        step = 0
        while step < self.num_iter:
            content_batch = self.content_iter.get_next()

            if content_batch[0].shape[1] != self.batch_size:
                content_batch = self.content_iter.get_next()

            style_batch = self.style_iter.get_next()
            
            if style_batch[0].shape[1] != self.batch_size:
                style_batch = self.style_iter.get_next()
            
            
            current_label = tf.constant( content_batch[1], shape=( 2, 1 ) ).numpy()
            loss_value = tf.Variable( 10.0 )
            
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                
                result = self.model( inputs=tf.constant( content_batch[0], shape=( 1, WIDTH, HEIGHT, CHANNEL ) ) )
                result = tf.constant( result, shape=( 2, 1 ) )

                predict_label = tf.Variable( tf.constant( self.model.trainable_weights[len(self.model.trainable_weights) - 1], shape=( 2, 1 ) ) )
                loss_value =  self.loss( result.numpy(), current_label )
                loss_value =  tf.Variable( tf.constant( loss_value, shape=( 1, ) ).numpy() )
                tape.watch( loss_value )
            
            gradients = tape.gradient( loss_value, loss_value )

            self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_weights))

            # log and save every 200 batches
            if step % 200 == 0:
                print(f'Training loss (for one batch) at step {step}: {self.loss}')
                print(f'Seen so far: {(step+1)*self.batch_size} samples')

                self.model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)

            step += 1

        print("Finished training...")
        self.model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Dataset
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
variables = pd.read_excel('F:\\temp\\Python\\excel\\Book 7.xlsx', index_col=None, header=[0], dtype=str)

train_image_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    create_image_generator,
    output_types=None,
    output_shapes=None,
    args=None,

    output_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=( 1, WIDTH, HEIGHT, CHANNEL ), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
        ),
    
    name='train_image_ds'
)

train_image_ds = train_image_ds.batch( 1 )
iterator = iter( train_image_ds )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( WIDTH, HEIGHT, CHANNEL )),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 127 * 127)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2),
])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=0.0000001,
    name='Nadam'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
gradient_tape_optimizer = gradient_tape_optimizer( model, num_iter, iterator, batch_size )
result = gradient_tape_optimizer.train()

input( '...' )
```